# How can I debug "Event loop is closed"?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I've been unable to debug this issue. I run my program and after maybe 30 seconds, I get this:

```
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000002504E200A60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pbssu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\pbssu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close  
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\pbssu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 751, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\pbssu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

I cannot debug this because I have no idea which coroutine this is caused by. I have multiple threads, each which has their own purpose. This callstack is not helpful.

Does anyone know what this is? Or how I could debug it?

Comment: You could debug it by removing coroutines or threads or other parts of your code until the error disappears.

Comment: Try to add enable debug mode on the `event loop`, have a look at the following link:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.set_debug, it might throw additional information before crashing